# Formula.Firewall issue with dataverse

Tags: powerquery, firewall, dataverse

I have an issue with my dataverse table that I'm transforming in PowerQuery. I need to do several calculations with several different results so I loaded the same table with the same source twice and then performed an left merge with those tables (with the same source).

However, when I perform the merge I get the error: Formula.Firewall: Query 'Projectdatums' (step 'Expanded Projectstatus') references other queries or steps, so it may not directly access a data source. Please rebuild this data combination. Which I never have if I use for example a SQL database. Hence I'm thinking this is because of the Dataverse source I'm using.

Any suggestions?

Comment: you need to go into home ... advanced editor ... and copy the code from your different queries, then edit your question and paste that in.  Otherwise we can't tell what is going on

Answer (score 1):

Solved the issue by loading the table 1 time and then referenced to that loaded table. Via tables that are referenced merging queries is possible again.